# Program runs fine in IDE but not as Jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have exported a jar file that I want to run the console. The code compiles and runs correctly in eclipse but I am having an issue running it from the console.

[image]

To me it looks like the referenced jar's I added via built path in the Eclipse project file and not being added to the export. If that is the case, how do I ensure that they do? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the order and export tick in your classpath under the project properties for your jdbc driver

Comment: add reference jars to projects lib folder

Comment: One another way to add that jars to classpath of environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export your source code's class files to a jar using eclipse, only the .class files of your source are exported! Hence your exported jar file doesn't contain the referenced jars you mentioned in eclipse! Due to this, the error occurs while executing from command prompt.

**Solution**:
Take all the jar files required to execute the program, store it in the same directory as you store the exported jar file. Now while executing the java command, provide all the jar file's names in classpath field as following:
*java -classpath .;JAR1.jar;JAR2.jar MainClass*
Once you do this, your problem should be resolved!

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies need to be on the classpath, i.e. run like this:

`java -cp <path_to_jar1>;<path_to_jar2> -jar ScrumTimeCaptureMaintenence.jar`

Comment: I added them to the path and I got the same error: java -cp C:\AAA\jars\sqljdbc4.jar;C:\AAA\jars\ScrumWorks-soap.jar;C:\AAA\jars\postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4.jar;C:\AAA\jars\hsqldb-2.2.8.jar;C:\AAA\jars\commons-lang-2.4.jar; -jar ScrumTimeCaptureMaintenence.jar

Answer (score 1):

When running from the command line make sure any dependencies are set on the class path by listing them in the `-classpath` parameter